# graphql object with an arbitrary/unknown field

Tags: php, graphql

let's say I have a resource `product` with fields like

- id
- name
- description
- externalSettings

and external settings is JSON field with unknown data, it can be any data set by the merchant, how can I describe it???

```
type Product {
   id: ID!,
   name: String!,
   description: String!,
   externalSettings ??? 
}
```

which type should be here, it's a JSON object but I can't describe internals as I do not know them, I just want to be able to query that json as whole and that's it

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing in js then I can recommend the [graphql-scalars](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/scalars/docs/scalars/json) package. It includes a JSON type along with many others.

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL allows to implement a [custom scalar](https://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Scalars.Custom-Scalars). You have to implement it for JSON .

Most probably I guess someone should already implement it for you depending on which GraphQL library / framework you use.

For example in the java world , I would simply use [graphql-java-extended-scalars](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars#object--json-scalars)